# How do I change music via command line

Tags: release-loki, audio

I have a new keyboard without media control, so I want use xbinkeys to ad a combination to play/pause, go to next and back song. How can I do this by commandl ine (change music).

Answer (score 0):

You already have this built-in.

Open Settings->Keyboard, open Shortcuts tab, then click on Media on the left side menu.

There you assign all related shortcuts.

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason, is not possible apply shortcut using `fn` + any other key.

Comment: research this post https://superuser.com/questions/428945/defining-keyboard-shortcuts-involving-the-fn-key

It may not be possible in your case (most likely). I advice you to settle down with ctrl/alt shortcuts